# Are these examples of comma-splice?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Are the following sentences examples of comma-splice?

> I am well, thank you.

> I have been sick, but I feel better now, thank you.

If just one is a comma-splice example, why is one acceptable, and the other not?

Comment: No comma splices there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [comma splice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice) is using a comma to join two independent clauses.  In these examples, "thank you" isn't an independent clause.  Rather, in these examples it's being used as an [interjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection) (sometimes listed in dictionaries as an [exclamation](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/thank-you)).

When an interjection appears in a sentence, you usually set it off with commas.  You can make it more emphatic by moving it into its own sentence, but it's not required, nor is it a comma splice if you fail to do so.

Comment: "Thank you **can be** an independent clause or merely an interjection. It depends on stress & intonation when spoken and on punctuation when written.